# Java EE - Getting InvocationTargetException while calling Remote Facade?

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, methods, remote-access, facade

I am trying to make an Enterprise Application but facing a very strange error.

Whenever i try to call enterprise application's facade from any class other than Main, I am get an InvocationTargetException.

Here is my code: -

```
public class TellerMachine {
    @EJB
    private static BillerFacadeRemote billerFacade;

    @EJB
    private static AccountFacadeRemote accountFacade;
    @EJB
    private static CustomerFacadeRemote customerFacade;
    @EJB
    private static BanktellerFacadeRemote banktellerFacade;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TellerMachine tm = new TellerMachine();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sssa = billerFacade.hiHAHAHAHA();
        System.out.println(sssa);
        tm.printABC();
        TestClass t = new TestClass();
        t.abc();
    }

    public void printABC()
    {
        String sssa = billerFacade.hiHAHAHAHA();
        System.out.println(sssa);  
    }
}
```

Test Class: -

```
public class TestClass 
{
@EJB
private static BillerFacadeRemote billerFacade;
public static void main(String[] args)
{

}
public void abc()
{
    try{
    String a = billerFacade.hiHAHAHAHA();
    System.out.println(a);}
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getCause().toString());
    }
}

}
```

Method in BillerFacade: -

```
@Override
public String hiHAHAHAHA() {
    return "abc";
}
```

Stack Trace: -

```
Warning: /Users/varunbatra/Desktop/RealApp/SwinBankTellerMachine/dist/gfdeploy/SwinBankTellerMachine does not exist.
abc
abc
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.launch(AppClientContainer.java:438)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.main(AppClientFacade.java:165)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at swinbanktellermachine.TestClass.abc(TestClass.java:29)
    at swinbanktellermachine.TellerMachine.main(TellerMachine.java:52)
    ... 6 more
Java Result: 1
```

Why it's like that? and sometime even i am calling the remote method from my Main class it still gives me this Exception. What's the matter with Netbeans? Sometime it works sometime it doesn't. Please Help and clear my confusion.

Comment: The stack says that the InvoicationTargetException is caused by a NPE, you have to start from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195365/injecting-a-static-ejb-nonsense) and the referenced EJB specification, `static` injection is only allowed in the application main class. Therefore, the injection works for your `TellerMachine` class but not for called `TestClass` instance from within the `TellerMachine` `main` method.